# I-95 Toll Stations From Newark NJ to Pentagon

Tags: tolls

A trip in a rental car from Newark to the Pentagon logged these tolls:

```
Transaction Date        Location                                    Amount  Agency Posting Date
10/21/2018 9:34:16 AM   Plaza-1-Delaware Memorial Bridge-Lane 15X   -$12.55 NJTP    10/21/2018 11:50:34 AM
10/21/2018 11:02:07 AM  Plaza-FMT-Fort McHenry Tunnel-Lane 015      -$4.00   MdTA   10/21/2018 5:20:23 PM
10/21/2018 9:51:15 AM   Plaza-D95-Newark Plaza-Lane 41              -$4.00   DelDOT 10/23/2018 2:22:15 AM
10/21/2018 9:39:41 AM   Plaza-DMB-Delaware Memorial Br-Lane 04      -$4.00   DRBA   10/23/2018 5:50:51 AM
```

I am concerned that a toll station may have missed MY (not the rental car company's) transponder.   Is there a list of toll stations that I can check against to determine if there was missed transponder reading?

## UPDATE

I actually started from Manhattan \ Lincoln tunnel.  I do not think there are any tolls from there to Newark, NJ, so I titled the post from Newark, NJ.

I've been burned by this problem in the past, where a toll station did not pickup my transponder, but it did record the plate.  The rental car company tagged me for the toll and additional fee (which was more than triple the toll).

Comment: I haven't done that drive in a few years but it seems right to me.

Comment: Note that the "Newark Plaza" collected by DelDOT is Newark, *Delaware,* not New Jersey.

Comment: Why would you care? It's the rental company's responsibility at the end of the day.

Comment: @jonathanreez no it's the renters responsibility.  Part of the agreement is that you become responsible for all tolls fines and penalties.

Comment: @Andy:  correct.  I am responsible.  I registered the vehicle plate with MY  iPass (Illinoise): they sent me a letter confirming.  When I checked online the plate was missing.  I think this has something to do with the fact that Hertz has an agreement with one of the toll agencies (can not remember which state)

Comment: @Andy, I once drove a rental car across a toll bridge, paid the CAN$3 toll online later, but due to crossed wires, the rental car agency was charged again. They billed me not just the toll, but a processing fee an order of magnitude larger than the toll. I had to FAX my receipt for the toll to the rental car company to have the charge reversed.

Comment: @MikeHarris it might also be a good idea to note that the pronunciation of the name of the Delaware city is different from that of the name of the New Jersey city.

Comment: @Andy sure, but if you drived through a toll and didn't pay, it will be up to the rental company to track that down, not vice versa.

Comment: @JonathanReez I really don't know what you're trying to get at.  Unless you think the OP should just blindly trust any bill the rental agency might send?

Comment: @Andy if there was in fact a toll that the rental company missed when sending the bill, its their problem and their problem alone. The toll agency doesn't care who the driver was, they'll want the toll paid by the owner of the vehicle. Hence OP shouldn't care about this issue at all.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think you're understanding the question; the OP used his own transponder, and wasn't sure if one of the tolls detected it or not, so he wants to check his records against a list of expected tolls...

Comment: @Andy but again, even if the transponder malfunctioned and the car wasn't detected, its the rental company's responsibility at the end of the day.

Comment: @JonathanReez NO, it is not.  The tolling authority will send a bill (and fine) to the rental company.  The rental company will know the OP was driving their car, and send a bill for the toll, fine, and their own penalty, and the OP agreed to such terms when he rented the car.  Its pretty clear you're not familiar with the NE US and the I-95 corridor, or renting a car in the US; please stop saying this won't end up back on the OP when you are uninformed.

Comment: @JonathanReez The toll agency won't care who pays, but they supply the rental agency more than enough data for them to locate (and charge, including hefty fees) the person who rented the car. This operates much the same way as an unpaid parking ticket; that will also eventually be billed to the renter's credit card, with (huge) fees.

Comment: It may help some readers to know that the $12.55 is a largely mileage based toll, but the bill (at least as presented here) does not show the corresponding _entry_ onto the NJ Turnpike, which is a toll road. I presume this was at the interchange leading to and from Newark (EWR) Airport. The Delaware Memorial Bridge is the southern point of the NJ Turnpike and perforce an exit. The $4.00 DMB toll is separate, for the crossing of the bridge itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct. The only toll station missing is the I-95 bridge over the Susquehanna (the Millard Tydings Bridge), but that toll is [only collected northbound](http://mdta.maryland.gov/Toll_Facilities/JFK.html), so you're OK.

Although your list isn't sorted by time, the toll stations you passed were:

- NJ Turnpike (Newark NJ - Del Mem Br): $12.55
- Delaware Memorial Bridge (NJ/DE state line): $4.00
- Delaware Turnpike, Newark DE: $4.00
- *no toll at Tydings Bridge*
- Ft. McHenry Tunnel, Baltimore: $4.00

This is assuming you didn't take any of the [express toll lanes](http://mdta.maryland.gov/ETL/I-95_ExpressTollLanes.html) northeast of Baltimore. The mainline lanes are not tolled.

Links:

- New Jersey Turnpike Authority: https://www.njta.com/toll-calculator
- Maryland Transportation Authority (MdTA): http://mdta.maryland.gov/Toll_Rates/rates_Index.html
- Delaware DOT: https://www.deldot.gov/public.ejs?command=PublicTollRateI95
- Delaware River and Bay Authority: http://www.drba.net/delawarememorialbridge.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the details in the response.  Is there a reference (link) to support the list?  I appreciate the good news.

Comment: I've added more links. MdTA is responsible for I-95 from the DE state line up to and including the Baltimore Harbor tunnels and bridge. DelDOT handles the DE Turnpike (I-95 in DE), and the DRBA is in charge of the bridge between NJ and DE.

Comment: Not authoritative, but potentially useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_95_in_Maryland#Exit_list also see similar pages for DE & NJ.

Comment: Links are appreciated and credit is awarded.

Comment: The other potential toll facility, depending on route, would be the Express Lanes on the Virginia side of the Capital Beltway, but it's perfectly possible to drive to the Pentagon and not encounter them.